# How to render a template file using shortcode inside a plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have this plugin I created that has a custom post type and a template file that renders the posts. 
I want to be able to render the template in any page using a short code. So what I created was this piece of code which I am sure is wrong and would totally appreciate it if someone could answer how I am supposed to render the template

```
function display_timeline(){

    ob_start();  
    locate_template(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/timelines.php', true, false);  
    $ret = ob_get_contents();  
    ob_end_clean();  

    return $ret;    

}

add_shortcode( 'wptimeline_display', 'display_timeline' );
```

Also, the template and the plugin functions are both in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

[`locate_template()`](http://wpseek.com/function/locate_template/) only look for a specific template in themes, not in plugins, so your function wil never work. This also goes for [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) which is in essence just a wrapper function for `locate_template()`.

You will need to use funtions like [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to check whether or not the required template exists and then use something like [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to load your template. You can use the above to write your own function like `locate_template()`, this is at least what I will do, and have a fallback to lacate a template in themes should the template not exist in the plugin.

Just a note, always always first check if a value/template/condition exists before doing something with it. This will avoid unnecessary bugs and issues should a failure occur. Also, have something in place like returning false, adding a redirect, exiting etc etc to safely handle your code should you have a failure

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `get_template_part('timelines');` instead of `locate_template(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/timelines.php', true, false);` I just given it a try and it works fine. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks but it didn't solve the issue on my end. I get a blank page as before

Comment: That is strange. Did you try turning your WP_DEBUG to true? Please let me know what errors you get so that I may assist.

Comment: What Pieter answered above makes sense.